# JSON dump order in Python

Tags: python, json

I am attempting to write to a JSON using a specific format.  I have attempted different methods of making the json.dump command to write to the file how the data is presented in the variables.  Any suggestions as attempted OrderDict and Sort-Keys, which was recommended previously and online.

**01/07/2020** - Here is the code for the order and the creation of the JSON file.

```
    data =[]
    subData=[]
    subData=media_add()
    data.append(OrderedDict(
        {
            "values": [ {
                "CaseID": case_id,
                "CaseMetadata": [
                    {
                        "CaseID":case_id,
                        "PropertyName":case_name,
                        "PropertyValue":case_value
                    }
                ],
                "CaseNumber": case_num,
                "ContactEmail": contact_email,
                "ContactName": contact_name,
                "ContactOrganization": contact_org,
                "ContactPhone": contact_phone,
                "ContactTitle": contact_title,
                "Media": subData,
                
                "TotalMediaFiles": len(final_results),
                "TotalPrecategorized": 0,
                
                "SeizureDate": autData[3][1],
                "SourceApplicationName": "Autopsy",
                "SourceApplicationVersion": autData[5][1]
                }]}))


    # Serializing json  
    json_object = json.dumps(data, indent=5)

    # Writing to json file

    filename= (case_name_fn + " " + date_fn + "." + time_fn + ".json")


    with open(filename, "w") as outfile: 
        json.dump(data, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False)
```

**Update 04/09/2020**
Good Afternoon, due to the specific requirements, the Python Code needs to be written in Python 2.7. I have attempted to redo the above work in 2.7 instead of 3.6 like the original code however I cannot get the dump to stay in the order written in the code. I have re-attempted to use OrderedDict but this has failed.

Is there another way to create a structed JSON file without using json.dump method.

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you add your code here and highlight the issue so that it can be easier to point out?

Comment: I presume it is the inner dictionary (the element in `values`) that you want sorted. Since CPython 3.6/Python 3.7 I would expect that the exact order the dictionary was created with would be preserved during JSON serialization (removing/changing keys later would change that, though).

Answer (score 1):

To get values printed in the same order that you inserted them you need to do two things:

- Do not set `sort_keys=True` as you did in your example of dumping to a file. This sorts them alphabetically, not by insertion order.
- Use at least Python 3.6.

The second one is necessary because, prior to Python 3.6, dictionaries did not remember the order that elements were inserted. If you set `x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}` then iterate over it then you might get elements back in the order `'a', 'b'` or `'b', 'a'`. It might even change between runs of the same program!

If you're stuck with Python 3.5 or older then you can use an `OrderedDict` instead. I see that's what you're doing now. But you use `{...}` literal syntax, which puts the values in a `dict`, so the order is already lost before it gets to `OrderedDict`. Instead you have to use lists or tuples:

```
data.append(OrderedDict(
    [
        ["values", [ [
            ["CaseID", case_id],
            ["CaseMetadata", [
                [
                    ["CaseID", case_id],
                    ["PropertyName", case_name],
                    ["PropertyValue", case_value]
                ]
```

... and so on. As you can see, it is quite fiddly; it probably better just to upgrade your Python version. Perhaps you are simply using Python 2.7 by accident, because that is often what you get by just running `python` at the command prompt. In that case, you might be able to fix your problem by just running `python3` instead.

Comment: For completeness sake: "Use at least Python 3.6" is only true as far is CPython is concerned. Python (the language) only guarantees this behaviour from version 3.7 on.

Comment: Thank you.  I update my Python, as I was running 2.7.  Updated to 3.8 and the JSON file was generated correctly and in order.  Thank you for the help

Comment: @L3viathan In addition, it is also true for even earlier versions of PyPy (which is the main alternative to CPython).